# HQL returns duplicate entities on simple query when ordering by EnumType.ORDINAL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, enums, hql

I'm trying to fetch a list of entities using Hibernate HQL in Spring MVC. The query looks like this:

```
SELECT m FROM MyEntity m where property =:property ORDER BY otherProperty desc
```

The problem is that I'm getting lots of duplicate results (same ID and Java hash), even when adding a `DISTINCT` keyword after the `SELECT` one. **This only happens** where ordering by the enum `OtherProperty` which is stored as `ORDINAL` (int) in MySQL. I've tried using Criteria and other methods, finding this kind of problem always.

Is there an easy solution to this problem? Moving the enum to EnumType.STRING is the last option I want to consider since it involves refactoring the database, but I'd like to hear suggestions on this if that's the only option you can think of.

The MyEntity entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="my_entity")
public class MyEntity extends BaseEntity<Long> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4L;

    @Searchable
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "property_id")
    private Property property;

    @Searchable
    @Column(name = "other_property")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private OtherProperty otherProperty;

    (...)
}
```

And the BaseEntity class looks like the following:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public abstract class BaseEntity<T> implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Searchable
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private T id;

    @Version
    private Long version;

    public Long getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Long version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public T getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(T id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And finally, the OtherProperty enum looks like this:

```
public enum OtherProperty { 
    VAL_A ("Hi"), 
    VAL_B ("Howdy"),
    VAL_C ("Aye");

    private String name;
    private OtherProperty(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this :   query.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

Comment: Sorry, just tried it. Just the same as adding the `distinct` sql clause, it still returns the same duplicates. I think this is a bug since the SQL sentence is so simple, without joins, that it should return every row only once.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this was probably the dumbest problem I've faced (my fault). My `equals(Object o)` method in the `MyEntity` class, which I had overridden, wasn't working properly, so Java couldn't actually tell one entity from another. Fixed that part, fixed the whole problem.

So, just in case this helps anybody else, please check your `equals(Object o)` methods if you are getting duplicates in HQL.